# How to add partial views in in a view in an orchardcore theme

Tags: asp.net-core, orchardcore

I converted layout.liquid to layout.csthml so I can see the syntax highlighting.

Then, how do I add partial views inside a view (layout.cshtml) in an OrchardCore theme?

I tried to call it

```
    <partial name="~/TheExperimentalTheme/Views/_MyPartial.cshtml" />

    <partial name="_MyPartial.cshtml" />
```

But no partial gets rendered.

The location of the partial view is inside another project - The theme

[image]

But what is rendered in page source is only

```
    <partial name="/TheExperimentalTheme/Views/_MyPartial.cshtml" />
```

The whole layout page is rendered so no error that says my partial is not found.

I tried to call

```
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_MyPartial")
```

and not the partial tag helper and I got this error

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The partial view '_MyPartial' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Areas/OrchardCore.Cms.Web/Views/TheTheme/Home/_MyPartial.cshtml
/Areas/OrchardCore.Cms.Web/Views/TheTheme/Shared/_MyPartial.cshtml
/Areas/OrchardCore.Cms.Web/Views/Shared/_MyPartial.cshtml
/Areas/TheExperimentalTheme/Views/TheTheme/Home/_MyPartial.cshtml
/Areas/TheExperimentalTheme/Views/TheTheme/Shared/_MyPartial.cshtml
/Areas/TheExperimentalTheme/Views/Shared/_MyPartial.cshtml
/Areas/OrchardCore.Roles/Views/Shared/_MyPartial.cshtml
/Areas/OrchardCore.Settings/Views/Shared/_MyPartial.cshtml
/Areas/TheTheme/Views/Home/_MyPartial.en-PH.cshtml
/Areas/TheTheme/Views/Home/_MyPartial.en.cshtml
/Areas/TheTheme/Views/Home/_MyPartial.cshtml
/Areas/TheTheme/Views/Shared/_MyPartial.en-PH.cshtml
/Areas/TheTheme/Views/Shared/_MyPartial.en.cshtml
/Areas/TheTheme/Views/Shared/_MyPartial.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_MyPartial.en-PH.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_MyPartial.en.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_MyPartial.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/_MyPartial.en-PH.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/_MyPartial.en.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/_MyPartial.cshtml

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialCoreAsync(string partialViewName, object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TextWriter writer)

Answer (score 0):

I placed it under the Shared folder in my theme project.